# ukuu + ubuntu 16.04 не устанавливаются последние версии ядра

Tags: ubuntu

Пробую установить ядра 4.16.4, 4.16.5 и 4.17.0-rc2. Выдает ошибку зависимости от пакета linux-modules-*. Ядра более старших версий устанавливаются без проблем. Пробовал чистить кеш программы и саму программу - не помогло.

Comment: 1. https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu/issues/69 2. скачайте нужные [пакеты](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16.4/), да поставьте. «особые программы» для этого вовсе не требуются.

Comment: Я скачал, хотел поставить lowlatency версию. Получил проблему с зависимостями. Теперь ни удалить не переустановить не могу. Можете подсказать порядок установки на примере rc2-lowlatency?

Answer (score 1):

если сравнить списки собранных файлов:

1. http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16.3/
2. http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16.4/

то можно увидеть, что для версии `v4.16.4` (забегая вперёд — и для последующих версий) модули программы *linux* собраны в отдельный пакет (а раньше шли в одном большом пакете вместе с самой программой). насколько я пониаю их «кухню», произошло это после [вот этого коммита](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/kernel-ppa/mirror/kteam-tools.git/commit/?id=1252369a02c1374f2d049fbd4f526c9470ae5f06):

```
From 1252369a02c1374f2d049fbd4f526c9470ae5f06 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Andy Whitcroft <apw@canonical.com>
Date: Mon, 23 Apr 2018 11:18:03 +0100
Subject: mainline-builds: include modules packages in results

Signed-off-by: Andy Whitcroft <apw@canonical.com>
---
 mainline-build/mainline-build | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

diff --git a/mainline-build/mainline-build b/mainline-build/mainline-build
index 5401c8e..0b6c684 100755
--- a/mainline-build/mainline-build
+++ b/mainline-build/mainline-build
@@ -101,7 +101,7 @@ sha1=`git log -1 --pretty=%H "$commit" 2>/dev/null`
 echo "mainline-build '$remotes' '$commit'${abi:+ '$abi' '$base' '$date'}" >"$html/REBUILD"
 "$here/mainline-extract-logs" "$master_main/BUILD.LOG" "$html/BUILD.LOG" "$master_main/BUILT"
 mv "$master_main/BUILD.LOG" "$html"
-mv "$master_main/"linux-{headers,image}-*.deb "$html"
+mv "$master_main/"linux-{headers,image,modules}-*.deb "$html"
 if [ -f "$master_main/CHANGES" ]; then
    mv "$master_main/CHANGES" "$html"
 fi
-- 
cgit v0.11.2
```

поэтому надо скачивать (и устанавливать) не только пакет с программой *linux* (например, [этот](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16.4/linux-image-unsigned-4.16.4-041604-lowlatency_4.16.4-041604.201804240433_amd64.deb)), но и парный ему [пакет с модулями](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16.4/linux-modules-4.16.4-041604-lowlatency_4.16.4-041604.201804240433_amd64.deb).

p.s. устанавливать — как и обычно:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i файл1 файл2 ...
```

---

багрепорт у разработчиков программы *ukuu* уже [имеется](https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu/issues/69). когда-нибудь они и подстроятся под изменения в убунтовской системе сборки для проекта [mainlinebuilds](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds).

Comment: Попробовал установить по wiki 4,17.0-rc2 вот: Настраивается пакет linux-image-unsigned-4.17.0-041700rc2-generic (4.17.0-041700rc2.201804230622) …
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.17.0-041700rc2-generic.postinst: 50: /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.17.0-041700rc2-generic.postinst: linux-update-symlinks: not found
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета linux-image-unsigned-4.17.0-041700rc2-generic (--install):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 127 Теперь ни снести, ни установить и ukuu пишет, что ядро установлено. Первый раз ставлю вручную.

Comment: написано же, что не найден пакет `linux-update-symlinks`. поставьте его из репозитория. // p.s. риторический вопрос: а стоит ли вообще такими низкоуровневыми системными вещами заниматься, как чехарда с linux-ами, если уровень представления о дебиановской пакетной системе столь низок?

Comment: Я и не собирался, Вы сами сказали что там элементарно и допсофт совсем не нужен, вот и решил попробовать. Помогите пожалуйста. Вот что гонит ошибку: cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.17.0-041700rc2-lowlatency.postinst ... linux-update-symlinks $change $version $image_path  Это как я понял часть пакета linux-base, который у меня уже установлен. Может другой какой-то дополнительный пакет еще нужен?

Comment: так /usr/bin/linux-update-symlinks у вас есть? если нету, то linux версии 4.17.0 собран без расчёта на вашу версию пакета linux-base, т.е. сносите его лучше к чёрту. // посмотрел: в вашей версии дистрибутива в linux-base нет такого скрипта. значит, однозначно, эта сборка рассчитана на более новую систему. сносите её.

Comment: Спасибо огромное Вам за помощь. Ничего не получилось и пока не получится, так как нужен новый обновленный linux-base для сборки, который еще не вышел. (удалить эти deb-ы тоже никак, так как не хватает еще одного скрипта)

Comment: удалить известно как: https://askubuntu.com/q/48014/416190 `$ sudo dpkg --purge --force-all имя-пакета`

Comment: https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu/issues/69 (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-base) поставил новый нерелизнутый linux-base и все сразу установилось. Может понадобится еще кому, а Вам Александр еще раз спасибо, буду непременно совершенствовать дальше свои навыки.